# How to check containment in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How can i chek if one value (e.g the string in A2) contains other value (e.g the string in B3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B3,A2)),"it's not there","it's there")
```

`FIND` returns the position in `A2` where `B3` is found, or `#VALUE` if it's not found.

`ISERROR` tests for `#VALUE`

Comment: thanks! it almost what i wanted. i managed to do this like this: =IF(ISERR(FIND(A2,B2)=TRUE,1,0)

Comment: it would be nice to get at least an upvote for that...

Comment: You got an upvote from me! ISERR is slightly better than ISERROR here as it excludes the case where B3 or A2 contain a #N/A themselves (small possibility, but better to exclude any cases we don't need to consider). @aharon: There is no need to do the =TRUE bit, simply ISERR(FIND(foo, bar)) will evaluate to TRUE or FALSE, so testing if TRUE=TRUE is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FIND() function; it returns the index of string1 in string2 if it exists, or error otherwise.